# Inverting a very fast clock signal

Tags: clock

How can I generate a inverted signal of a 20MHz Clock signal synchronous to the original signal? (At least, very close to the original)

With a typical HEX INVERTER the propagation delay is already too high (5-10ns).

Should I use a single-ended to differential IC? Couldn't find any references on the internet.

Comment: What is your propagation delay limit?

Comment: I don't really have a "propagation delay limit" I just really want the two clock signals in sync.

Comment: You try looking through a distributors site ? This is a digikey search for "inverter" filtered by "max prop delay < 2ns"  http://www.digikey.ca/product-search/en?pv1552=357&pv1552=102&pv1552=344&pv1552=290&pv1552=402&pv1552=134&pv1552=307&pv1552=215&pv1552=201&pv1552=97&pv1552=396&pv1552=174&pv1552=350&pv1552=390&pv1552=428&pv1552=286&FV=fff40027%2Cfff8019d&k=inverter&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25

Comment: What is this for?

Comment: look for zero delay buffers. eg http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/clock-and-timing/zero-delay-buffers-products.page

Comment: @pjc50 Got a SRAM which is triggered by a rising edge. I want to invert that (so I can do stuff on the rising edge and the save the data on the falling edge)

Comment: You could apply the skew in the other direction (route the noninverted signal through two inverters), so you get more time between the rising edge and falling edge but less time between falling and rising.

Comment: @pjc50 Yes, I thought of that too. This would indeed solve my problem with the SRAM but the main point I'm asking here is because I'm on the search of a more elegant and generic solution (also for other future projects).

Comment: @efox29 Those sites have always the problem of filtering the products in the right way. I found a inverter with a typical delay of 5ns. But the maximum delay time for that inverter was still specified at 20ns room temperature. Also, I searched for "high speed hex inverter" which gave me even worse results.

Comment: @d3l thats fair. I've only had one issue with the site not being accurate with the datasheet. It's still my goto place to find part numbers or series for me to dive deeper into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a buffer with *complementary outputs*, such as http://www.idt.com/products/clocks-timing/clock-distribution-ics/fanout-buffers-clock-dividers-and-multiplexers/8302i-01-low-skew1-2-lvcmoslvttl-fanout-buffer-w-complementary-output

Comment: Sounds great! I guess the outputs are then more in sync because both signals experience about the same propagation delay?

Comment: Yes, the device will be designed to give near-identical propagation delay on each path. Note that if you're laying out 74 logic on a PCB you'll have to watch out for skew in the clock wiring.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks